# Trying to add Graph in Android Studio but keep getting this error

Tags: android, graph, build.gradle

It says that,  Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

```
buildscript{
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}



// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
allprojects{
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and I already put this on my dependencies

```
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
```